# Deleted Cloudformation Stack, now unable to recreate new ones due to resources already existing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I ran into a condition that caused my stack to become unrecoverable and I had no choice but to delete it. Using the exact same template, I went ahead and created another stack with the same name.

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [AdminPanelCDNAccessIdentity, 
BackendLogGroup, BackendLoadBalancerSecurityGroup, AdminPanelCertificate, 
EnvironmentCertificate, AdminPanelBucket, BackendECSTaskRole, 
BackendECSTaskBitbucketAccess2RunTask, BackendLoadBalancerTargetGroup]. The 
following resource(s) failed to update: [FrontEndBucket].
```

Do I really need to delete all these resources manually and rebuild them from scratch? That seems like a terrible option.

Here's a sample snippet of my template code

```
Resources:
FrontEndBucket:
Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
Properties:
  BucketName: !If 
    - IsProduction
    - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${LandscapeStack}-DNSDomain'
    - 'Fn::Sub':
        - '${EnvironmentSubdomain}.${LandscapeDomain}'
        - LandscapeDomain:
            'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${LandscapeStack}-DNSDomain'
  AccessControl: Private
  Tags:
    - Key: landscape
      Value: !Ref Landscape
    - Key: environment
      Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  WebsiteConfiguration:
    IndexDocument: index.html
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
    id: 53eb6c3a-767f-46fb-a719-2846f1fd6bdd
FrontEndBucketPolicy:
Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
Properties:
  Bucket: !Ref FrontEndBucket
  PolicyDocument:
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 's3:PutObject'
          - 's3:GetObject'
          - 's3:DeleteObject'
        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${FrontEndBucket}/*'
        Principal:
          AWS:
            'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${CIResourcesStack}-BitbucketFrontEndPipelineUser'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 's3:ListBucket'
        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${FrontEndBucket}'
        Principal:
          AWS:
            'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${CIResourcesStack}-BitbucketFrontEndPipelineUser'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 's3:GetObject'
        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${FrontEndBucket}/*'
        Principal:
          CanonicalUser: !GetAtt FrontEndCDNAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
    id: f8d2a536-790c-4cbe-adcb-b50754c0922e
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably selected to retain all of the resources that failed to delete when you deleted the stack. CloudFormation will not adopt existing resources into the stack. You will need to manually delete all of the resources that were created by the old stack before you can deploy this exact same stack. Or you can change the names of the resources before you deploy again.

Comment: Will I need to store data from any of those resources  before deleting them though?

Comment: Yes if you need the data you will need to copy it else where, in this case I would change the names of the resources in the cloudformation template so I have a place to copy the data to.